# How to passing a list with Navigator.pop() in flutter/dart?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

This is my second screen code and want to pass the list to the first screen. my question is how to get my list in FIRST screen?
second screen code:

```
static List<dynamic> att = [];
Navigator.of(context).pop(att);
```

what should I do in my first screen and how to get my list?

Comment: check https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation

Comment: Navigator.pop(context, att);
please try this one. might solve your problem

Comment: @MuhammadTameemRafay how about the page i get data? what should I do?

Comment: on the first page you have to await for the response from the second page. 
final res = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
    );

Answer (score 1):

To get the data back from the second screen you need to pass the attributes like this:

```
static List<dynamic> att = [];
Navigator.pop(context, att);
```

Now on the screen you are pushing a route on the stack, you need to catch the pop variables wherever you are using **Navigator.push** like bellow:

```
final result = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
    );
```

Now you have data returned back from the screen, You can also refresh the screen here (setstate bellow the await call). If you are using a button to push make sure you are using async on the onpressed.

For step by step details of how it works refer this : [Article](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data)

Answer (score 0):

On the first screen call it with a dynamic variable and await a result.

```
dynamic result = await Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/{{routename}}');
```

then when you pop the second screen return the values in a map as follows:

```
 static List<dynamic> att = [];
 Navigator.pop(context, {
    'list': att,
 });
```

The list returned can be accessed via the `result` variable once the second screen has been popped.

Comment: I have problem with your code. **Unhandled Exception: Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/{{routename}}", null) in the _WidgetsAppState. Make sure your root app widget has provided a way to generate this route**. @OshadaPalitharathna

Comment: @AshkanAA have you read https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation? it has a lot of examples on how to use navigator API

Comment: yes i did but did't get something. @pskink

Comment: @AshkanAA it has a link named: `Return data from a screen`

Comment: To use the `Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/{{routename}}')` you need to have a Router defined in your `main.dart` file. Or create a router linking each of your screens, and call it in the `main.dart`. As an alternative you can use the following:

`dynamic result = await Navigator.push(context, secondScreenName());`